How to save a file in SharePoint with library properties - Power Automate
I have docx document that contains proprieties fields mapped to SharePoint library proprieties, so when editing the SharePoint library propriety it will be reflected in the document proprieties fields.
Using Power Automate:
When saving the docx file in OneDrive, the file will be saved with filled proprieties fields.
But when trying to save the file in a SharePoint folder, the file will be saved without proprieties data (fields are empty).
I tried to do a trick and save the file first to OneDrive then to SharePoint but no success.


Can you show an example screenshot of your column setup in the library and an example of what you used in your Word document, I assume Plain Text Content Controls?
